# Can I capture keypad values with an analog pin?

Tags: arduino-uno, c++

I am building a calculator with an Arduino Uno. The thing is I ran out of pins. The switch membrane has 4 rows and 4 columns resulting in 8 pins it doesn't fit. That is why I plan to do a shift register (PISO,) but there is a slight problem: I don't know how. Also, I don`t know if I could use the analog pins for the rest of the keypad pins.

What I would do if I had enough pins is this:

```
// Keypad
const byte ROWS = 4; // number of rows
const byte COLS = 3; // number of columns
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1', '2', '3'},
  {'4', '5', '6'},
  {'7', '8', '9'},
  {'*', '0', '#'}
};

byte rowPins[ROWS] = {8, 7, 6, 5}; // row pinouts of the keypad R1 = D8, R2 = D7, R3 = D6, R4 = D5
byte colPins[COLS] = {4, 3, 2};    // column pinouts of the keypad C1 = D4, C2 = D3, C3 = D2
Keypad keypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS);
```

I can't, so yep, I have a 74HC595N module or I could use the analog pins. Any hints on how to solve this? I have 5 pins available for the membrane pins, and I need to be able to read what I press on the keypad.

I'm not doing a schematic because I'm bad at it and it would only confuse, hopefully, it's enough.

Comment: For one thing, the 74HC595N is a SIPO not a PISO. So it won't give you extra inputs. Besides that, a PISO isn't going to be sufficient, you will need both a PISO and a SIPO. The keypad needs 4 inputs and 4 outputs, and a PISO or SIPO will need 3 I/O lines, but you can combine the clock and latch pins to end up with 4.  See https://www.instructables.com/Shift-Register-Keyboard-for-Arduino/ for an example.

Comment: Hello Akko and welcome ... circuit diagrams are the lifeblood of electronics ... respectfully I'd suggest you try drawing one for your issue.  It's the only way to get better at them.

Comment: Thanks, I will try

Comment: you can buy a keypad that uses a resistor network, and requires only one analog pin ... or you can make your own ... research `arduino analog keypad schematic` ... a library is available for ease of programming

Comment: Can`t I use the analog pins for the rest of the keypad pins?

Comment: all of the "A" pins can be used for digital I/O if you don't need them for some other purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a circuit, that provides unique voltage dividers per each button. The more buttons you use, the smaller is the voltage difference between buttons. These 12 buttons can be identified with enough margin for ADC noise as long as the wires are short.

However, if more than one button is pressed at a time, the result is wrong. Either it looks like another button or is out of range.

The software should read the values twice with a short delay (2..5 ms) in between. The button should only be calculated if these values are nearly the same, because there are times when the voltage rises or falls on button press or release, passing values of other buttons.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2jG7T.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The upper resistor values of the divider are 4.3k, 8.4k, 13.3k, 16k, 20.1k, 25k, 28k, 32.1k, 37k, 40k, 44.1k and 49k, the lower resistor is 1k here. You can play with the simulator and try different buttons and see the different voltages.

A software loop like "Serial.println (analogRead (pin));" will give you the values of the buttons you need for the calculation.

Comment: Thanks, I will try

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both ideas will work.

You can use analog pins to read buttons.

You can also use the HC595 to have as many digital buttons you want by creating say 1 by N matrix where N are the outputs to matrix scanning and come from HC595.

Comment: Thanks, if you can help me, how would I implement it in the code?

Comment: I don't know what language you want to use and what exactly you want to implement. Reading ADC, doing matrix scanning or controlling a HC595 are trivial tasks typically not longer than 10 lines of code each and there should be plenty of examples. Do some research about each subject.

Comment: I am researching, maybe I'm close to the answer

Comment: I´m not. Maybe I'm just dumb because it is a relatively easy problem that shouldn´t require extra hardware but I don´t seem to find a plausible option, the analog pins work way differently from the digital ones, and I don't know what to do.

Comment: Should I post this on Arduino exchange?